How to Resolve 'Dummy Output' Issue with PulseAudio on Ubuntu 24.04
I’m encountering an issue on Ubuntu 24.04 where PulseAudio displays 'Dummy Output,' and my soundcard isn’t being recognized.
I’ve tried downgrading the kernel from 6.8 to 6.5 as advised by the answer to Fixing No Sound (Dummy Output) Issue in Ubuntu 24.04 which also did not resolve the issue.
How can I fix this issue and get my soundcard recognized properly?

For 24.04.1:
Unlike in plain 24.04, the solution is now running this and resetting.
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service

From what this command tells me, I'm using PipeWire Pulse Audio, since everything else comes up with errors.
systemctl --user status pipewire{,-pulse} wireplumber

For 24.04:
Run the following then reset your computer, that's what fixed it for me, since I didn't want to downgrade:
systemctl --force --user --now enable wireplumber.service

Further info:
This seems to be a continuing issue from 22.04 onwards, since I found an answer to a 22.04 version of this problem, then looked up the error messages that I got from attempting and led me to this answer which got me to the code above that worked after a reset.
